# cs50 pset4 filter swapping structs

Tags: c, struct, cs50

I'm facing some difficulties while doing the reflect portion of filter. Essentially the struct is

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

and I have been attempting to reflect the image by implementing this function.

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        if (width % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width/2; j++)
            {
                RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
                image[i][j] = image[i][width - j];
                image[i][width - j] = temp;
            }
        }
        else if (width % 3 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (width - 1)/2; j++)
            {
                RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
                image[i][j] = image[i][width - j];
                image[i][width - j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The code compiles fine but the end product is the same as the input image. Tried to run debug50 and i figured that my problem lies with the way i swap the RGBTRIPLE values. Any help would be good. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of width? Pay attention to that in any case your code has undefined behavior. At least you have to use image[i][width - j -1]

Comment: Your code only does something if `width` is a multiple of 2 or 3, which doesn't cover all numbers. I think your `else if (width % 3 == 0)` should simply be `else`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You are entirely wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ah, indeed I am, sorry about that.

Comment: `width % 3 == 0` is a pretty weird thing to test. Why does it matter whether the width is a multiple of 3? How wide is the image that is not working for you?

Comment: @interjay i followed your advice but i still ended up with the same problem. Could it be that the algorithm itself is wrong?

Comment: I pointed out one problem. Vlad pointed out another, and there may be more.

Comment: thank you for tips, I've gotten it to run already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to reverse the array.

Why? because you are reflecting image horizontally so you want the left side of the image to become the right side of the image.

Imagine you have this array and you want to reverse it:

```c
int count = 5;
int numbers[count] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

// middle here should be 2.5 but it will be 2 because we cast it to int
int middle = count / 2;
// Reverse array
for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
{
    // when i is 0, numbers[i] is 0, numbers[count - 1 - i] is 4
    temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[count - i - 1];
    numbers[count - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

You should do the same in your function:

```c
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // The middle index
    int middle = width / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < middle; j++)
        {
            // Swap the left side element with right side element
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
            image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```